# GridView Adapter not detecting clicks on the last cell

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView Adapter that operates in two modes. In one mode, when a cell is clicked, it will open up an Activity with bigger picture of what was in the cell displayed. In the other mode, SelectMode, each cell has a check box displayed in it and upon cell clicks, the checkbox is either set or cleared, and a number of selected cells is displayed in the Activity title bar.

When I switch to the select mode, then the last cell in the grid does not seem to receive the click. The reason I say "seem" is that when I click some other cell, the selected count displayed in the title bar reflects the selection of the last cell, even though the OnClick event is never called when the last cell is clicked and the checkbox is never set in the last cell. The number of cells in the Grid View is variable, but it's always the last cell that is having this problem.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code for the BaseAdapter that is backing up the GridView, I am guessing the problem is somewhere in the getView().

Thank you,
Gary

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private GridView.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFloomitApp.GetPhotoCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFloomitApp.GetThumbUrl(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_item, null);

            viewHolder.imageView = (RecyclingImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_grid_item_thumb_image);
            viewHolder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_grid_item_check_box);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setId(position);
            viewHolder.imageView.setId(position);
            viewHolder.id = position;
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mThumbSelection[position]);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
                    int id = checkBox.getId(); 
                    mPrevSelectCount = mSelectCount;
                    if (mThumbSelection[id]) {
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        mThumbSelection[id] = false;
                        if (mSelectCount > 0) {
                            mSelectCount--;
                        }
                    } else {
                        checkBox.setChecked(true);
                        mThumbSelection[id] = true;
                        mSelectCount++;
                    }
                    SelectMode(mSelectMode);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id = v.getId(); 
                    if (mSelectMode) {
                        CheckBox checkBox = viewHolder.checkBox;
                        if (mThumbSelection[id]) {
                            checkBox.setChecked(false);
                            mThumbSelection[id] = false;
                            if (mSelectCount > 0) {
                                mSelectCount--;
                            }
                        } else {
                            checkBox.setChecked(true);
                            mThumbSelection[id] = true;
                            mSelectCount++;
                        }
                        SelectMode(mSelectMode);
                    } else {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ImageDetailActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE, (int) id);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, FloomitGlobals.FLOOMIT_PHOTO_DELETE_REQ_CODE);   
                    }
                }
            });

            convertView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else { 
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (mSelectMode) {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(CheckBox.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(CheckBox.INVISIBLE);
        }


        if (convertView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            convertView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }

        mThumbFetcher.loadImage(getItem(position), viewHolder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }


    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams =
                new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
        mThumbFetcher.setImageSize(height);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        RecyclingImageView imageView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        int id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setId(position);
viewHolder.imageView.setId(position);
viewHolder.id = position;
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mThumbSelection[position]);
```

should also execute whenever `convertView != null`.

When you scroll on a `ListView` or `GridView`, views what exit the screen are placed in a *recycler*. Whenever a new row needs to be created, a recycled view will be used if there is one available. This is to make scrolling faster, since creating views from scratch is expensive.

The problem is that since you only set these values when a new view is created, the first reused view will have *the id it had before that view was recycled* instead of the correct one.